# Why are my images overflowing the window with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have created a showcase section where in I have used flexbox to align images to the right. However when I shrink the size of the window, the images go out of the window. I am looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xLc2Le0k/15/

Here is the snippet for HTML:

```
<div class="showcase shadow">
      <div id="places">
        <p class="category">Places</p>
        <div>
          <img src="img\Taj Hotel.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="img\Gateway of India.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="img\Shack at Goa.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <p class="more-text">View more...</p>
    </div>
```

Here is the snippet for SCSS:

```
.showcase {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 5%;
      display: inline-block;

        #places {
          width: 100%;
          display: flex;

            div:nth-of-type(1) {
              align-self: flex-end;
            }

            div {
              margin-left: 0.5%;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is the link for the live web page: https://swizzx.github.io/Photography-Portfolio/

Just a heads up, I have tried setting the width of the parent and the element to 100%, when I do so, it shrinks but does not work as how I want it to like in the JSFiddle provided above. On the contrary setting the width to 100% makes the first image equal to the size of the others which I don't want.

Comment: `am looking for something like this` --> so use it, no ? you have the code and what you want

Comment: I have already mentioned it doesn't work in my case hence I have posted my code to see what am i missing or doing wrong

Comment: Hi Swizzx, typically if your issue is not with Sass itself, or how to write something *in Sass*, it's better to provide the compiled CSS.

Comment: Actually my question is how should i make an image fluid with flexbox and prevent it from overflowing the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was the paragraph in the #places div that was causing the images to shrink much more than required. Figured out that had to place it out of the #places div and inside the .showcase div like :

```
<div class="showcase shadow">
      <p class="category">Places</p> // like this
      <div id="places">
        <div>
          <img src="img\Taj Hotel.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="img\Gateway of India.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="img\Shack at Goa.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <p class="more-text">View more...</p>
    </div>
```

and than setting the width of the images to 100% like gagan mentioned :

```
.showcase {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: inline-block;

    #places {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;

        div:nth-of-type(1) {
          align-self: flex-end;
        }

        div {
          margin-left: 0.5%;

            img {
              width: 100%; //width to 100%
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add below css property to the flex container. It wraps elements automatically to the next line when you shrink the window.

flex-wrap: wrap;

Answer (score 0):

One thing you are missing in your code is applying 100% width to your img tag. Give img 100% width and it will work the same way you want.

```
#places div img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, if I do so it does not preserve its aspect ratio with the window size it keeps shrinking and than disappears

Comment: I tried it in jsfiddle and the aspect ratio is preserved. https://jsfiddle.net/05jw3eyx/1/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback!